# How to develop an Import/Export Functionality for my node application

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, algorithms, import, export

I have a configuration application in Nodejs. It has a `Component` with `name` and `uuid`. A `Component` can have many `Schemas`. A `Schema` has a `uuid`, `name`, `componentId`, `json`. A `Schema` can have many `Configurations`. A `Configuration` has `name`, `schemaId`, `json` and `uuid`. A `Schema` can contain reference of many other `Schemas` in it. Now I want to create a functionality of exporting all the data from one instance of the application `( in json format in file )` and import it in another. What should be the simplest way to do it? a few questions are

1. How to tell application what to export. for now i think there should be separate arrays for components, schemas and configurations. Like

```
{
    components: ['id1', 'id2'],
    schemas: ['s1', 's2'],
    configuration: ['c1', 'c2'],
}
```

this data should be sent to application to return a file with all information that will later be used for importing in another instance

1. The real question is how should my export file look like keeping in mind that dependencies are also involved and dependencies can also overlap. for example a schema can have many other schemas referenced in its json field. eg `schema1` has `schema2` and `schema4` as its dependencies. so there is another schema `schema5` that also require `schema2`. so while importing we have to make sure that `schema2` should be saved first before saving `schema1` and `schema5`. how to represent such file that requires order as well as overlapped dependencies, making sure that `schema2` is not saved twice while importing. `json` of `schema1` is shown below as an example

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "p1": {
        "$ref": "link-to-schema2"
    },
    "p2": {
        "$ref": "link-to-schema4"
    },

}
```

3. What should be the step wise sudo algorithm i should follow while importing.